# Delphi 7: access designer from component source code

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

Example component:

```
unit LDBCheckBox;

interface

uses
  Classes,DbCtrls,Db;

type
  TLDBCheckBox=class(TDBCheckBox)
  private
    FImmediateUpdate : boolean;
    function GetDataField: string;
    procedure SetDataField(const Value: string);
  protected
    procedure Click; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TCOmponent);override;

  published
    property ImmediateUpdate : boolean
      read FImmediateUpdate write FImmediateUpdate
      stored true default true;

    property DataField: string
      read GetDataField write SetDataField;
  end;

  procedure Register;

implementation
uses
  LDbUtils, DesignIntf;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('LDb',[TLDBCheckBox]);
end;

constructor TLDBCheckBox.Create(AOwner: TCOmponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FImmediateUpdate := true;
  ValueChecked := '1';
  ValueUnchecked := '0';
end;

procedure TLDBCheckBox.Click;
begin
  if ImmediateUpdate then
    if CanModifyField(self.Field,self.DataSource) then
      if DoAutoEdit(self.DataSource) then
      begin
        if self.Checked
          then SetFieldValue(Field,self.ValueChecked)
          else SetFieldValue(Field,self.ValueUnChecked)
      end;
  inherited Click;
end;

function TLDBCheckBox.GetDataField: string;
begin
  Result := inherited DataField; 
end;

procedure TLDBCheckBox.SetDataField(const Value: string);
begin
  inherited DataField := Value;
  if Assigned(Field) then
    if Field.DisplayLabel <> '' then
    begin
      self.Caption := Field.DisplayLabel;
      if csDesigning in ComponentState then
        GetDesigner.Modified;
    end;
end;

end.
```

(Please ignore CanModifyField, DoAutoEdit and SetFieldValue functions - you can imagine what they do.)

I'm missing the part "GetDesigner.Modified". There I should be able to access the current component designer, and call its Modified method. That is required so that the IDE will update the Caption property's value. But how do I get an IDesigner instance for a property? Is there a method for that?

BTW. I know how to create a custom property or component editor, and then call IDesigner.Modified from there. However, this is not what I want in this case. Because all database aware components are using a simple dropdown for field names. I do not want to change that, so I do not want to register a new property editor or component editor. All I want is to call the designer's modified method. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to create a custom property or component editor, and then call IDesigner.Modified from there. However, this is not what I want in this case. Because all database aware components are using a simple dropdown for field names. I do not want to change that, so I do not want to register a new property editor or component editor. All I want is to call the designer's modified method. But how?

I'm afraid that you will need to put any code that refers to the IDE's designer into a separate design time package. The rules are that design time code using `ToolsAPI` must not exist in a run time package. It must be separated into a design time package.

A property editor is, I think, the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, but how do I register that component designer? In order for a component designer to be used, it must first be registered with the RegisterComponentEditor procedure. From a component editor instance, it is possible to access the designer using the TComponentEditor.Designer property, and then it can be used. However, I do not see how a component editor could solve my problem. The component editor is created and opened when the user double clicks the component. But this is not what I want. I want to update the caption when DataField property is changed. Is that possible?

Comment: Or maybe I can create a component designer that also has a listbox for the datafield property. But they would be very clumsy. As I said before, all data-aware components are using a list for selecting the data field. I do not want to change this. That would distract the user.

Comment: Sloppy terminology from me. I think you need a property editor. That will allow you to take actions when properties change.

Comment: In other words: create and register a TPropertyEditor descendant with RegisterPropertyEditor, return [paSortList] from its GetAttributes method. Also override the GetValues(Proc : TGetStrProc); method, and return fieldnames from there. Then what? How do I cache the "property was set" event? I can do it from the original component's SetDataField method, but the designer won't be available there.

Comment: Ok but then how can I create a property editor that displays a selectable list, and access the event when the user has selected an item in the IDE? There must be a way, right?

Comment: I expect so, but it's hard to do this in comments and I think I answered the original question.

Comment: Answer accepted. But I still don't know how to do this exactly with a property editor. The TPropertyEditor class does not define any events. Just methods and properties. I cannot find a way to access the designer when the user changes the property value by selecting an item in the list.

Comment: `TPropertyEditor` has a virtual `SetValue()` method that you would override, and a `Designer` property that you would call `Modified()` with. But this is overkill, because the base functionality already does this for you. The OI is already monitoring property changes and should be automatically updating the `Caption` when the `DataField` is set, without you having to write any extra code to force it.